installation error bootstrap
2024-09-02 04:58:00.419460 INFO flavor_provider: Using default flavor: UbuntuFlavor.ubuntu
2024-09-02 04:58:00.419624 INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds
2024-09-02 04:58:00.428340 INFO subiquity_server: ApplicationState.ERROR
2024-09-02 04:58:00.428394 INFO subiquity_client: Opening socket to Endpoint(/run/subiquity/socket )
2024-09-02 04:58:00.428612 DEBUG desktop: Disabling automounting
2024-09-02 04:58:00.430340 DEBUG subiquity_client: POST http://localhost/meta/client_variant?variant=%22desktop%22
2024-09-02 04:58:00.437726 DEBUG telemetry: Writing report to /var/log/installer/telemetry
2024-09-02 04:58:00.438075 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> setVariant(Variant.DESKTOP) null
2024-09-02 04:58:00.439867 INFO subiquity_status: null => ApplicationStatus(state: ApplicationState.ERROR, confirmingTty: /dev/tty1, error: ErrorReportRef(state: ErrorReportState.DONE, base: 1725267075.924834967.install_fail, kind: ErrorReportKind.INSTALL_FAIL, seen: false, oopsId: null), nonreportableError: null, cloudInitOk: true, interactive: true, echoSyslogId: subiquity_echo.2488, logSyslogId: subiquity_log.2488, eventSyslogId: subiquity_event.2488)
2024-09-02 04:58:00.439922 DEBUG subiquity_client: POST http://localhost/meta/mark_configured?endpoint_names=%5B%22mirror%22%2C%22proxy%22%2C%22ssh%22%2C%22snaplist%22%2C%22ubuntu_pro%22%5D
2024-09-02 04:58:00.440849 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> markConfigured([mirror, proxy, ssh, snaplist, ubuntu_pro]) null
2024-09-02 04:58:00.450964 DEBUG desktop: Disabling screen blanking
2024-09-02 04:58:00.453715 DEBUG desktop: Disabling screensaver
2024-09-02 04:58:00.455229 DEBUG desktop: Inhibiting Gnome session
2024-09-02 04:58:00.834615 INFO subiquity_status: null => ApplicationStatus(state: ApplicationState.ERROR, confirmingTty: /dev/tty1, error: ErrorReportRef(state: ErrorReportState.DONE, base: 1725267075.924834967.install_fail, kind: ErrorReportKind.INSTALL_FAIL, seen: false, oopsId: null), nonreportableError: null, cloudInitOk: true, interactive: true, echoSyslogId: subiquity_echo.2488, logSyslogId: subiquity_log.2488, eventSyslogId: subiquity_event.2488)
2024-09-02 04:58:00.834847 INFO subiquity_status: null => ApplicationStatus(state: ApplicationState.ERROR, confirmingTty: /dev/tty1, error: ErrorReportRef(state: ErrorReportState.DONE, base: 1725267075.924834967.install_fail, kind: ErrorReportKind.INSTALL_FAIL, seen: false, oopsId: null), nonreportableError: null, cloudInitOk: true, interactive: true, echoSyslogId: subiquity_echo.2488, logSyslogId: subiquity_log.2488, eventSyslogId: subiquity_event.2488)
2024-09-02 04:58:00.834882 DEBUG subiquity_client: GET http://localhost/meta/interactive_sections
2024-09-02 04:58:00.835356 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> getInteractiveSections() null
2024-09-02 04:58:00.835595 INFO locale: Loaded 75 languages
2024-09-02 04:58:00.835613 DEBUG subiquity_client: GET http://localhost/locale
2024-09-02 04:58:00.837087 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> locale() "en_US.UTF-8"
2024-09-02 04:58:00.837140 INFO locale: Selected en_US as UI language
2024-09-02 04:58:00.857889 DEBUG subiquity_client: GET http://localhost/meta/status
2024-09-02 04:58:00.860171 DEBUG subiquity_client: ==> status() {"state": "ERROR", "confirming_tty": "/dev/tty1", "error": {"state": "DONE", "base": "1725267075.924834967.install_fail", "kind": "INSTALL_FAIL", "seen": false, "oops_id": null}, "nonreportable_error": null, "cloud_init_ok": true, "interactive": true, "echo_syslog_id": "subiquity_echo.2488", "log_syslog_id": "subiquity_log.2488", "event_syslog_id": "subiquity_event.2488"}
2024-09-02 04:58:00.860214 INFO subiquity_client: state: null => ERROR

does anyone know how i can fix this? installing on a Asus Prime Z790-A wifi motherboard with 2TB wesatern digital Sata HDD
